# Spring boot, usando o banco h2 para testes

Tags: java, spring-boot, testes-automatizados

Eu uso o postgresql, porém para os testes quero usar o banco H2, como faço o spring reconhecer o banco H2 para os testes?
Criar outro application.properties passando os dados do h2?
***estou usando o mybatis ao invés do JPA

````
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver ```
````

Comment: insira a anotação @ActiveProfiles("test") na sua classe de teste

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar um arquivo `.properties` com a sigla `-dev`, assim você pode indicar o profile no momento de executar seu projeto.

Exemplo:

**Maven**

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev
```

Veja também: [how-to-use-spring-boot-profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060989/how-to-use-spring-boot-profiles)